# Connecting to remote SQL Server instance using SQL auth via SqlPowershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlps

I'm trying to use SqlPowershell/SqlPS (`Import-Module sqlps`) to connect to a server on my local network.  I followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231287.aspx) to create a function that predefines a server/database and the login and prompts each time for the password:

```
function sqldrive
{
    param( [string]$name, [string]$login = "<myLogin>", [string]$root = "SQLSERVER:\SQL\<serverName>\<databaseName>" )
    $pwd = read-host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Password"
    $cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $login,$pwd
    New-PSDrive $name -PSProvider SqlServer -Root $root -Credential $cred -Scope 1
}
```

However, after running `sqldrive <someName>` and entering my password, it fails to connect, giving two messages:

```
WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt to connect to WMI on '<serverName>' failed with
the following error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
```

and

```
New-PSDrive : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Path SQLSERVER:\SQL\<serverName>\<databaseName> does not exist. Please
specify a valid path.
At line:6 char:5
+     New-PSDrive $name -PSProvider SqlServer -Root $root -Credential $ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\<serverName>\<databaseName>:String) [New-PSDrive], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathDoesNotExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?  I can work with the same server just fine using those credentials via SSMS.

Comment: Since it's a WMI error, have you tried enabling WINRM on the remote system?

Comment: How is WMI connected to WINRM?

Comment: On the target machine, I ran `winrm quickconfig`.  It said WinRM was already running, but the firewall wasn't configured.  It asked if I wanted it to add the firewall exception and I said yes.  I'm still seeing the same result as the original post.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @unlikely Yup, sorry for not updating the thread.  Perhaps not what you're looking for, but I eventually discovered that I could just construct the database object and pass that to `-InputObject` instead of setting up a PS drive.  The easiest way to do that is `$db = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $myConnectionString`